# reshape data.frame from wide to wider

Tags: r

I want to go to storing all the contents of a data.frame in one row.

Something like this:

```
c = structure(list(V1 = c("1", "2", "3"), V2 = c("1.1",  "2.2", "3.1"), V3 = c("1.4", "2.8", "3.5")), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3"), row.names = c("a", "b", "c"), class = "data.frame")
d = as.data.frame(t(as.data.frame(c(c[, 1], c[, 2], c[, 3]))), row.names = NULL)
colnames(d) = c('a.1', 'b.1', 'c.1',
                'a.2', 'b.2', 'b.2', 
            'a.3', 'b.3', 'b.3')
```

So that the output looks like:

```
                          a.1 b.1 c.1 a.2 b.2 b.2 a.3 b.3 b.3
c(c[, 1], c[, 2], c[, 3])   1   2   3 1.1 2.2 3.1 1.4 2.8 3.5
```

The way I'm doing it now requires me to know the right number of rows in `c` before I transform it. Is there anyway to work around this restriciton?

Comment: Isn't this `as.data.frame.list(unlist(c))`

Comment: Its not clever to name objects like functions, but you can try: `unlist(c)`

Comment: Yes. Yes it is.